Handle promisified pipeline
In my app I'm processing a certain type of files. During the upload process I'm using the following pipelining of the read and write streams:
import { pipeline } from 'stream';
import { promisify } from 'util';
const streamPipeline = promisify(pipeline);

try {
     await streamPipeline(file.stream(), fs.createWriteStream(tempPath));
} catch(err){
     console.log(err)
}

This general approach of doing promisify(pipeline) seems to be common, e.g. this article.
Now, when I upload a corrupt file my whole app crashes and I don't get any sort of error output, despite having a try-catch block around it. I have found out that this might be the reason for it.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to incorporate the solution that is suggested in the git issue, as the callback in my case is pipeline
I saw that there's actually a promise version of pipeline in Node. I tried this but this doesn't change anything.
Any idea how to fix this problem and make the code snippet more robust in case of a corrupt file?
MWE (hope this kind of works):
try {
    const formData = await req.formData();
    let file;

    if (!(Array.from(formData.keys()).includes('file'))) {
        throw new Error('No file uploaded');
    } else {
        file = formData.get('file');
    }

    // Validate file type
    if (!file || typeof file !== 'object' || !file.name || !file.name.endsWith('.avro')) {
        throw new Error('Invalid file type. Only .avro files are allowed');
    }

    const tempDir = './temp';
    if (!fs.existsSync(tempDir)) {
        await fs.promises.mkdir(tempDir, { recursive: true });
    }

    const tempPath = `${tempDir}/${file.name}`;

    await streamPipeline(file.stream(), fs.createWriteStream(tempPath));
  } catch (error) {
      logger.error(error)
      return new Response("upload error", {
        status: 500,
      });
  }


This issue is likely happening because some errors in the pipeline can emit events on the streams themselves rather than being caught by the try-catch block around await streamPipeline(...). Specifically, when there’s an error in the file upload (like a corrupt file), it may be emitting an error event on the stream, which needs to be caught by an error event listener directly on the streams involved.

If that's the case how would I do this?
I quickly tried to attach an event listener like so:
`const fileStream = Readable.from(file.stream());
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(tempPath);

fileStream.on('error', (err:any) => {
  console.error('File stream error:', err);
  writeStream.end();
});

writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Write stream error:', err);
  fileStream.destroy();
});`

No change.

"when I upload a corrupt file my whole app crashes and I don't get any sort of error output" - please provide more details. What is your "whole app" doing? How does it crash? Are you doing any processing of the file contents, and how did you corrupt them?

try {
await streamPipeline(fileStream, writeStream);
console.log('File saved successfully');
} catch (err) {
console.error('Error during pipeline processing:', err);
} should make a change

@bergi
I'm processing .avro files with my app. Up to this point in the code, I'm not doing much with the file. Just retrieving the file object out of some formData and doing some naive pre-checking regarding file ending etc.
I cannot tell how the corrupted file was changed or was made corrupted.

@no_doubt
I already had it in a try-catch, just not it mentioned for space reasons. But for the sake tried to add your code suggestion exactly in the same way and it's still the same.

Please share your actual code then, and ideally a sample file that lets us reproduce the issue. There is no obvious deficiency in the snippet you posted so far.

@Bergi
Shared a code snippet above.
Regarding the file, I can't share it and I don't know how it was generated. Cross-checking with the avro-tools.jar of Apache I get the Error: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -5474674564

I have found the issue on why the Error doesn't get catched.
This snippet await streamPipeline(file.stream(), fs.createWriteStream(tempPath)); or more generally promisify(pipeline) is handled differently depending on the Node Version.
Originally I have tried it with v22 and it completely crashed my App without catching the error.
However, with v20 the snippet doesn't cause any problems. But I don't know why.
